# AutoUIC ignore "ui file not found" before proprocess

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, c-preprocessor, automoc

I have a file who look like this :

```cpp
    ...

    #ifdef IS_COMPILE_FOR_SPECIAL_TARGET
        #include "ui_myPage_special.h"
    #else
        #include "ui_myPage.h"
    #endif
```

The project use [AutoUIC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC.html) to include `ui_` files. But since AutoUIC is called before the prepocessor, it ignore my `#ifdef` statement and try to replace the `ui_myPage_special.h` despite the `.ui` don't exist in this project.

*The error message* :

```
AutoUic error
-------------
"SRC:/path/to/mySource.cpp"
includes the uic file "ui_myPage_special.h",
but the user interface file "myPage_special.ui"
could not be found in the following directories
...
```

---

A solution I looked for was if AutoUIC can, in case it didn't find file, replace the `#include` by a `#error` or just leave it as is. So it's the preprocessor who will raise the error, and not AutoUIC.

I tried to find if an [autouic-option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/AUTOUIC_OPTIONS.html) like this exist but I didn't find this one in the CMake documentation.

Comment: Then mark the source file with [SKIP_AUTOUIC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/SKIP_AUTOUIC.html#prop_sf:SKIP_AUTOUIC) and run uic by yourself with [qt_wrap_ui()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/qt_wrap_ui.html)

Comment: Thank you but I have a lot of source file and a lot of project. That why I am searching a solution like a CMake global option rather than a "file by file" solution.

Comment: qt_wrap_ui() takes a list of ui files...